# children() ignores absolute elements on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very specific situation that I didn't know it is possible. The DOM structure as the Chrome sees it looks like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="1></div>
   <div id="div2" style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 122px; width: 128px; height: 12px;"></div>
   <div id="3"></div>
</body>
```

So, the element with absolute position is added to the body element. However, when I try to select all body's children with jQuery, there's no `div2`, which makes sense:

```
$('body').children() // returns div1 and div3
```

Now, is there a way with jQuery or pure JS, to get all the elements as the browser sees them with children() or any other method? In this case, I want't all 3 elements. I don't really have access to the web page, I can just inject JS to manipulate the DOM, so I am looking for a JS solution.

Comment: `when I try to select all body's children with jQuery, there's no div2, which makes sense:` - no it doesn't actually

Comment: @Tushar That's because you fixed the broken HTML. You can't just change the code and then claim that it works. -.-

Comment: @Siguza I thought that was copy-paste error while adding code to the question, and did you see the title of the question

Comment: @Tushar The title only means that the OP failed to correctly determine the source of the error, not that the actual source can just be discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
<div id="1></div>
//--------^
```

You didn't close the `id`. So the browser treats it as a single div, adding up with the `"` of the second div. So if you give the syntax correctly:

```js
$(function () {
  alert($("body").find("div").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="div2" style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 122px; width: 128px; height: 12px;"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

> ***Note:*** I have given `find("div")` in the above example as the snippet adds more code.